# parsing a masive csv file having a problem with bad version number of the software how do i format quickly 5 million rows

Tags: python, parsing, semantic-versioning

Here's a sample of my data:

```py
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""software,version
Visual C++ Minimum Runtime,11.0.61030
Visual C++ Minimum Runtime,11.0.61030
Visual C++ Minimum Runtime,11.0.61030.0.0.0.0""")
```

Notice that the last record the version number has `0.0.0.0` in it .

How can I get to `xx.yy.zz` first front 3 characters and clean up the remaining data?

As an example: `Visual C++ Minimum Runtime,11.0.61030.0.0.0.0` should be truncated to:

```py
"Visual C++ Minimum Runtime,11.0.61030"
```

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could use the `csv` and `re` modules. csv.reader will read rows, line by line, use `re` as a regular expression to truncate the stirng. And then csv.writer to write.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generators to load the file row by row and then write the truncated rows to a backup file.
eg.

```py
import csv

filename = "foo.csv"

def get_row(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as csvfile:
        data = csv.reader(csvfile)
        yield next(data)

with open('truncated.csv','wb') as truncatedcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(truncatedcsv, delimiter=',')
    for row in get_row(filename):
        truncated_row = # your truncation logic
        writer.writerow(truncated_row)
```

Don't forget to rename the new file and delete the old one.